# How to use multiple mics while streaming on twitch local

Tags: xbox-one, twitch

Me and my family have been streaming some games on our Xbox One but we've only been able to get one mic working. Is there a way to make it so all of us can be heard on stream? We tried all getting into a party but still only one works. I know a capture card would work but I was hoping for a cheaper solution. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Do you all have separate accounts that are logged into Live?

Comment: Yes, we all have Xbox Live and can play online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitch will only capture audio for the microphone that belongs to the player that logged into twitch, respectively the player that started Twitch. As only one account can be logged in at a time, that is the one the sound will stem from.

There is a functionality to co-stream on Xbox One, I think using Mixer. You might want to give it a try.